# ExcelDNA - Creating a table: xlcAddListItem or another way

Tags: c#, excel, excel-dna

I'm trying to figure out how to use `ExcelDNA` to create a table from an `ExcelReference` range.

With Excel you would usually do something like:

```
range2.Worksheet.ListObjects.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcRange, range2, System.Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes, System.Type.Missing).Name = "uniquesomething";
```

I've been trying to do something similar with `ExcelDNA` using `xlcAddListItem`, but it's pretty rough without any proper documentation.  Has anyone had any success?  Basically take the `ExcelDNA` array resizer example and then take the grid output and turn it to a table.

So far I tried

```
ExcelDna.Integration.SourceItem mySourceItemHopefully = (ExcelDna.Integration.SourceItem)XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlcAddListItem, 1, myExcelReference);
mySourceItemHopefully.Name = "uniquesomething";
```

But I get an access violation error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you will have to use the COM object model, which you can safely use from inside an Excel-DNA add-in as long as you:

1. use `ExcelDnaUtil.Application` to get hold of the root `Application` object, and
2. make all COM object model calls from the main thread in a macro or COM callback context.

You might need to get a COM Range object from the `ExcelReference`.

This can be as simple as:

```
static Range ReferenceToRange(ExcelReference xlref)
{
    string refText = (string)XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlfReftext, xlref, true);
    dynamic app = ExcelDnaUtil.Application;
    return app.Range[refText];
}
```

(Here the 'dynamic' Application might also be typed as a `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application`, if you have a reference to the PIA assembly.)

For more complicated ExcelReferences with multiple rectangles, you can start with the VB.NET code from here: https://github.com/Excel-DNA/Registration/blob/882517eed2137d2b2f9b4b794803258d20e5a174/Source/ExcelDna.Registration.VisualBasic/RangeParameterConversion.vb

---

Adding Tables is not supported by the C API. Microsoft have not extended the `xlcXXX` macros to cover newer features in recent versions of Excel (since Excel 2000). (However, the list of `xlfXXX` functions have been kept up-to-date until Excel 2013.)

The two macro functions you list do not refer to the type of tables you are making - you can see this in the MacroHelp help file that you can find here: http://www.xceed.be/Blog.nsf/dx/excel-macro-function-help-file-for-windows-7

**ADD.LIST.ITEM (`xlcAddListItem`):** *"Adds an item in a list box or drop-down control on a worksheet or dialog sheet control."*

**TABLE (`xlcTable`):** *"Equivalent to choosing the Table command from the Data menu. Creates a table based on the input values and formulas you define on a worksheet. Use data tables to perform a "what-if" analysis by changing certain constant values in your workbook to see how values in other cells are affected."* So this is about Data Tables, which are different to the 'ListObject' tables you're trying to create.